# only allow value from certain object as type

Tags: typescript

I want to use `MyBar` as an enum replacement. So in my function `testme` I want that the parameter `value` can only be `1|2`. How can I achieve this?

```js
const MyBar = {
  Benchpress : 1,
  Squats : 2
};

testMe(MyBar.Squats); // Error Argument number is not  assignable to parameter `Benchpress| Squats`

// I would like to use it like this:
testMe(MyBar.Squats);
testMe(2);
// And this should be an error 
testMe(3);


function testMe(value:  keyof typeof  MyBar)
{
  console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the custom `ValueOf` Type with a combination of `as const`

```js
const MyBar = {
  Benchpress : 1,
  Squats : 2
} as const;

type ValueOf = typeof MyBar[keyof typeof MyBar];

testMe(MyBar.Squats); // works
testMe(2); // works
testMe(3); // doesn't work


function testMe(value: ValueOf) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type MyBarValue = typeof MyBar[keyof typeof MyBar];
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**